# Regex to split a address string

Tags: regex

So I'm a real rooky with REGEX and I usually get my way through it back reference a static word in the string and then using just basic functions to find what I need, this one has me stuck though

So I have this address string "MITCHAM SA 5062" and to go through this parser i need to split the suburb, state and postcode.

I can get "MITCHAM" using `/\w+/`
And postcode "5062" using `/\d+/`
The state I'm struggling with though. I think I'm close, I'm currently using `(?!\w+) (\w+)` Issue here is it is still picking up the whitespace before the suburb which won't be allowed in the database.
Halp pls!

Edit - Few questions about if the state will ever be more than two letters - correct it could be. It won't always be SA

Edit 2 - Another person asked if one while regex can capture it all - No, the way our SaaS product works, I need to map each bit of data to the correct place separately (using a GUI)

Comment: Please include more sample data.  For example, can the suburb ever be more than one word?

Comment: You should include the full regex string

Comment: What language are you using? Consider catching all parts at once such as `^(\w+) (\w+) (\d+)$`

Comment: Also, is the order always the same, and is the state ever anything other than two letters?

Comment: I assume "SA" is South Australia, so to @Amadan's point, you'll need to catch multi-word and hyphenated county names, as well as three-letter states, like NSW.

Comment: In any case, presumably, the states can be exhaustively enumerated, so a simple alternation should do for that part. However, to echo others, a larger sample of data would be required to say anything definite.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hey mate. This is the only bit of data I have been given by the customer, but to answer your question
Yes the state should be able to capture up to any about of characters, this is the same with all 3 of them, that's why I put the + on the end so that it keeps going until it hits whitespace to ensure it is as robust as possible

Comment: @alexpdev This is literally the entire string, it's a .csv file parser, so the example I gave is what is in 1 cell

Comment: What language are using?

Answer (score 0):

If `MITCHAM SA 5062` is the full string, and you want to capture each group in one regex than this will work:

```
^(\w+)\s*?(\w+)\s*(\d+)
```

If you are trying to capture the middle section only you can try:

```
\s(\w+)\s
```

Or if for some reason you cannot use capturing groups, this will work for the middle portion.

```
(?<=\s)(\w+)(?=\s+)
```